# Using paperclip with an existing column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have an existing database column called "profile_picture" which is currently a text column. I would like to use the paperclip gem to allow users to upload their own "profile_picture".

What is the best way for me to approach this problem? Should I remove the "profile_picture" column and run the new paperclip migration or can I somehow modify this column and add the associated file_name, content_type etc. fields?

Answer (score 0):

Since the procile_picture is not a column that paperclip typically uses (the attribute `profile_picture` uses the column [`profile_picture_file_name`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)) there is no need to remove the column. It is, however, confusing to have column in your database that doesn't map to the similarly named attribute (because the set and get methods are provided by paperclip), so I would rename it probably before generating the paperclip... or better: simply remove the column if it is of no use. Try to tidy up whenever you can.

I would strongly recommend against renaming the column to `profile_picture_file_name` because it might contain data that paperclip cannot deal with.

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :users, :profile_picture, :old_profile_picture
    add_attachment :users, :profile_picture
  end
  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :profile_picture
    rename_column :users,  :old_profile_picture, :profile_picture
  end
end
```